# CSHTML page error by jquery when C# List

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have code accessing C# IList elements

```
if (@Model.List.Count>0) 
{
    minDateRange= '@Model.List[0].DatePurchase';
 }
```

If the List is empty , still Javascript evaluates the list and raises an error.
Is there any way to handle this

Comment: found the solution use the <text> </text> tag and with Razor IF    var minDateRange; 
    @if (@Model.List.Count>0) 
    {  
        <text> 
            minDateRange= '@Model.List[0].DatePurchase'; 
        </text> 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would use `Model.List.Any()` to check if there are any items.

Second, make sure that `if` statement resides within the razor syntax - thus you'll have :

```
@if (Model.List.Any()) {
minDateRange= '@Model.List[0].DatePurchase';
}
```

Comment: parameter minDateRange is declare inside body load as java script parameter , if i change the @if i get following error "The name 'minDateRange' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Could you show us the rest of your view (.cshtml)? That would probably help us out here quite a bit.

Comment: found the solution , if i use the <text> </text> tag with Razor IF works 
    var minDateRange;
    @if (@Model.List.Count>0) 
    { 
        <text>
     minDateRange= '@Model.List[0].DatePurchase';
 </text>
    }

Answer (score 0):

i think the element at the 0th element of the list is null 
so the count is still > 0 and you are getting a null reference error when accessing `Model.List[0].DatePurchase`

Comment: i did check that list is empty its just at client side it evaluates the statement on the right hand side

Comment: i did check that scenario whenever the list is empty , i encounter this error

Answer (score -1):

The `if` statement seems to be executing on the client, not the server. Try making the `if` part of the razor syntax like this:

```
@if (Model.List.Count > 0) {
    @:minDateRange= '@Model.List[0].DatePurchase';
}
```

Or in case `@Model.List[0].DatePurchase` is a string that might contain a `'` character (and would break your JavaScript string literal), consider using the [`Json.Encode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method:

```
@if (Model.List.Count > 0) {
    @:minDateRange= @Json.Encode(Model.List[0].DatePurchase);
}
```